# What are good places to guerilla/stealth/free camp with a hammock tent?

Tags: budget, tips-and-tricks, camping, long-term

In order to stretch my dollars, I plan on stealth camping in my hammock tent (dark green and modded with extra-long webbing straps) as much as possible. I know to generally pick either secluded spots or well-concealed spots, but I'm wondering if there are any particular places in towns and cities that are usually a safe bet.

Comment: Which city? Country? Continent? It differs from place to place, even within a single country (different state laws etc).  As it stands, it's likely to be closed as too broad (see the [help] for more details)

Comment: This question would fit better on [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 3):

I've done this in Thailand, New Zealand, Australia, and the U.S. During the day, the main thing I look for are large-ish clump of trees and bushes off to the side away from foot traffic. I've found these at the side of roads away from buildings and sidewalks, at the far end of low-trafficked parking lots, and other misc. places. I try to avoid city parks, as you are more likely to be noticed.

Another option is to find access to a rooftop. I personally have had success at hotels and hostels as it doesn't draw attention. However, bear in mind that depending on your whereabouts, getting caught may have severe consequences.

In the years of doing this, I've been caught a few times. In my experience, even irate people respond well if you're friendly, respectful, and don't lie. I say I will leave if they want but otherwise I will be gone before sunrise without leaving a trace. I've never been asked to leave, and one time I even got promoted to a couch hidden under a hostel staircase!

Edit: found a relevant thread on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vagabond/comments/3exhyp/stealth_urban_camping_tips/).

Comment: While stealth camping in public space like parks or forest areas is one thing, sneaking into hotels to sleep on their roof is blatant trespassing and possibly defrauding an innkeeper in some juristrictions.

Comment: I don't see the two as different. When I camped outdoors in Laos, the communist police told me I was breaking the law and stealing from the party. The locals I spoke to about it never cared. At the end of the day, I follow my own moral compass. Is occupying an empty space, discretely, leaving it as I found it without disturbing anyone a crime? If I don't affect their business and cause burden, my answer is no.

Comment: @RovingRichard, When it comes to sleeping on a hotel roof-top it probably doesn't matter if you think it is a crime or not.  That is private property and most jurisdictions have laws about that, whether you agree with them or not.

Comment: @cdkMoose I agree, changing laws by having personal beliefs is not one of my superpowers :)

Comment: "Is occupying an empty space, discretely, leaving it as I found it without disturbing anyone a crime?" In many jurisdictions that is actually a crime, which will both be prosecuted and result in a verdict against you. If that fits your moral compass or not is unfortunately not particulary relevant.

Comment: Nobody here is in disagreement. I'm clearly using the word "crime" in the "serious wrongdoing" sense, not legal sense. I don't understand the controversy. I see people saying "this practice isn't strictly permitted but in practice it's fine" on this site all the time. Just search "free camping" and read the answers.

Comment: Remove your suggestion about roof top sleeping and you might end the controversy.  For that act is criminal trespass in the "legal sense", plain & simple.  And one guiding principle of this forum is not to encourage or assist with law breaking.

Comment: As per [this discussion in meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3445/31045) I have clarified in my answer that there are potential consequences. I believe my answer conforms to the community standards and gives people the ability to make their own informed decision, but just in case I've flagged my answer to let a moderator take a look.